# Adding a Google Apps account to Android L with External Authentication

Tags: google-account, 5.0-lollipop

I want to add a Google Apps account to my phone with Android L.

When I put in my username and hit next, it redirects to a page and says I do not have authentication. This isn't strange, for some reason my admins make you authenticate with an Active Directory login. However, I do not even get the opportunity to put in my credentials. Here is a screenshot of what I see:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9MMQCxmnf8nZFA2M2tQRTI2ZU0/edit?usp=docslist_api

Going into incognito mode on chrome, I can get to the login prompt, but I can't continue adding my account from there:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9MMQCxmnf8nMHRQUm9wUHZOVzQ/edit?usp=docslist_api

I haven't had this problem with previous versions of android. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The first error is not a google error page. I don't know what steps you did, or what type of account but that is an Error page for a Windows ASP.NET server, which google doesn't use. If this is the redirection to one of your companies services, you should contact your IT department. Google Apps accounts work fine in L, I have 7 Google Apps accounts tied to my phone, and 1 Gmail account.

Comment: @RyanConrad I understand, this was referenced in my question. I doubt my IT department would know how to solve this either. I was wondering if there was a way that I could "hack" it so I could bypass that secondary authentication somehow.